# Substring indexes off in simple map reading program

Tags: java, string

Alright, so I'm trying to create a simple RPG game, and my map reading code seems to be off.
This is the map reading line:

```
Integer.parseInt(map.data.substring(Map.MAP_START + ((playerPOS - map.width)/2) - 1, Map.MAP_START + ((((playerPOS - map.width)/2) - 1) + map.dataLen)));
```

Now the only tiles in the map are 01 and 00, so when I see a 10 I know something is wrong:

```
(playerPOS - map.width) = 34 playerPOS = 50 player.x = 2 player.y = 3 blah = 0
(playerPOS - map.width) = 18 playerPOS = 34 player.x = 2 player.y = 2 blah = 10
```

Here is the map reading code:

```
public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
        map = new Map();
        player = new Player();

        keys = new boolean[ALL_KEYS];
        for(int i = 0; i < ALL_KEYS; i++){
            keys[i] = false;
        }

        file = new File("testmap.txt");

        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);

            bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int ch = 0;

            while ((ch=bin.read())!=-1) {
                sb.append((char)ch);
            }

            map.data = sb.toString().replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
            System.out.print(map.data);

            map.width = Integer.parseInt(map.data.substring(map.dataOffs, map.dataOffs + map.dataLen));
            map.dataOffs += map.dataLen;

            map.height = Integer.parseInt(map.data.substring(map.dataOffs, map.dataOffs + map.dataLen));
            map.dataOffs += map.dataLen;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tiles = new Image("tiles.png");
        hero = new Image("hero.png");
    }
```

and here is the map file:

```
16 12
01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

So if anymore info is needed let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend re-thinking the data structure for your map (perhaps a 2D array).  In your `init` method, read the text file token-by-token (assuming each token is whitespace-separated).  This is similar to what you're doing now, but you can avoid replacing the whitespace with empty strings.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

The first token string (in your example, "16") can be converted into `map.width` as you're doing.  Likewise, the second token becomes `map.height`.  Then you can loop through the remaining tokens in the following manner (pseudocode):

```
for(int y = 0; y < map.height; ++y) {
  for (int x = 0; x < map.width; ++x) {
    mapArray[x][y] = nextTokenAsInteger;
  }
}
```

Then, when you desire to know what the room looks like at position `(x, y)`, you simply access `mapArray[x][y]`.